# Bootstrap expanding cards causing issues with Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm working on collapsible cards for a webpage using Bootstrap 4. However, when I try to use a bootstrap navbar combined with these cards, the navbar shows up with a lot of blue links. Also, the hamburger menu isn't showing up at all.

Here is a link to my CodePen.

https://codepen.io/asizemore/pen/ExaRPwL

Does anyone know why it might be doing this and how to fix it?

```css
/* cards */

.card {
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #333333;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px #0000007a;
}

.card-body {
  padding: 0px 15px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
}

.panel-default {
  border: none;
}

.panel-group {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body,
.panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.list-group {
  border: none;
}

.panel-group .panel {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.panel-body {
  min-height: 250px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
  padding: 0px 15px 10px;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.panel-heading {
  text-align: center;
  padding: -5px;
  height: 65px;
  border: none;
}

.panel-button {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #999999;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: -13px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.panel-button .plus-minus:before {
  content: "\f067";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}

.panel-button[aria-expanded="true"] .plus-minus:before {
  content: "\f068";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}

a.panel-button:hover,
a.panel-button:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.panel-button {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333333;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px #0000004a;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .card {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    min-height: 300px;
  }
  x .panel-body {
    max-height: 300px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
  }
}


/* IMAGES */

.card-img-top {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.nametext {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.card {
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #333333;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px #0000007a;
}

.card-body {
  padding: 0px 15px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
}

.panel-default {
  border: none;
}

.panel-group {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body,
.panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.list-group {
  border: none;
}

.panel-group .panel {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.panel-body {
  min-height: 250px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
  padding: 0px 15px 10px;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.panel-heading {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 65px;
  border: none;
}

.panel-button {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #999999;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: -13px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.panel-button .plus-minus:before {
  content: "\f067";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}

.panel-button[aria-expanded="true"] .plus-minus:before {
  content: "\f068";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}

a.panel-button:hover,
a.panel-button:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.panel-button {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333333;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px #0000004a;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .card {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    min-height: 300px;
  }
  .panel-body {
    max-height: 300px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
  }
}


/* IMAGES */

.card-img-top {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.nametext {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- NAVBAR -->
<div id="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</div>


<!-- Cards -->
<div class="container">
  <!--  ROW 1   -->
  <!--         CARD 1 HECTOR -->
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">

      </div>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <a class="panel-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne"><span class="plus-minus"></span></a>
            <h3 class="nametext"> Hector Sr. </h3>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica. </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- card-body -->

      <img src="https://loe.org/content/2016-01-15/t-SOTU-President_Obama_Pete_Souza.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Responsive image">

    </div>
    <!-- card -->
  </div>

  <!--         CARD 2 ODALYS -->
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">

      </div>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <a class="panel-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo"><span class="plus-minus"></span></a>
            <h3 class="nametext"> Odalys Marrero </h3>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica. </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- card-body -->

      <img src="https://s1.r29static.com/bin/entry/576/720x864,85/2179893/image.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="Responsive image">

    </div>
    <!-- card -->
  </div>

  <!--         CARD 3 THE WORKERS -->
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
      </div>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion3" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
            <a class="panel-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree"><span class="plus-minus"></span></a>

            <h3 class="nametext"> The Workers </h3>

          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica. </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- card-body -->

      <img src="http://cdn.ipsnews.net/Library/2016/06/27232514444_bb9af40fcd_z.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Responsive image">

    </div>
    <!-- card -->
  </div>

  <!--    ROW 2 -->
  <!--         CARD 4 HECTOR LUIS -->
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">

      </div>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion4" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFour">

            <a class="panel-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour"><span class="plus-minus"></span></a>
            <h3 class="nametext"> Hector Luis </h3>
          </div>

          <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFour">

            <div class="panel-body">

              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- card-body -->

      <img src="https://c.stocksy.com/a/m8p500/z9/1388228.jpg?1571081157" class="card-img-top" alt="Responsive image">

    </div>
    <!-- card -->
  </div>

  <!--         CARD 5 PEDRO HECTOR -->
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">

      </div>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion4" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFive">
            <a class="panel-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion5" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive"><span class="plus-minus"></span></a>
            <h3 class="nametext"> Pedro Hector </h3>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFive">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica. </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- card-body -->

      <img src="https://marketplace.canva.com/MADFZPLwpN4/1/thumbnail_large/canva-young-mexican-man-MADFZPLwpN4.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Responsive image">

    </div>
    <!-- card -->
  </div>

  <!--         CARD 6 HECTOR MANUEL -->
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
      </div>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion6" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingSix">
            <a class="panel-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion6" href="#collapseSix" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSix"><span class="plus-minus"></span></a>

            <h3 class="nametext"> Hector Manuel </h3>

          </div>
          <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingSix">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica. </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- card-body -->

      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/85/c4/dd/85c4dd94e2bfda2f04e49bce1a729ed2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Responsive image">

    </div>
    <!-- card -->
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have added the code. Please check. If any changes please let me know.

Comment: If its right then please give me feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code. Hope it will help you. You haven't applied properly Bootstrap 4. So please check it. I have mentioned the link in the code. If any changes please let me know.

```css
/* cards */

.card {
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #333333;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px #0000007a;
}

.card-body {
  padding: 0px 15px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
}

.panel-default {
  border: none;
}

.panel-group {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  
}

.panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body,
.panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.list-group {
  border: none;
}

.panel-group .panel {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.panel-body {
  min-height: 250px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
  padding: 0px 15px 10px;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.panel-heading {
  text-align: center;
  padding: -5px;
  height: 65px;
  border: none;
}

.panel-button {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #999999;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: -13px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.panel-button .plus-minus:before {
  content: "\f067";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}

.panel-button[aria-expanded="true"] .plus-minus:before {
  content: "\f068";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}

a.panel-button:hover,
a.panel-button:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.panel-button {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333333;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px #0000004a;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .card {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    min-height: 300px;
  }

  x .panel-body {
    max-height: 300px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
  }
}


/* IMAGES */

.card-img-top {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.nametext {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.card {
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #333333;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 20px #0000007a;
}

.card-body {
  padding: 0px 15px;
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
}

.panel-default {
  border: none;
}

.panel-group {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body,
.panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.list-group {
  border: none;
}

.panel-group .panel {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.panel-body {
  min-height: 250px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
  padding: 0px 15px 10px;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.panel-heading {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 65px;
  border: none;
}

.panel-button {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #999999;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: -13px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.panel-button .plus-minus:before {
  content: "\f067";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}

.panel-button[aria-expanded="true"] .plus-minus:before {
  content: "\f068";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
}

a.panel-button:hover,
a.panel-button:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.panel-button {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333333;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px #0000004a;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .card {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .card {
    min-height: 300px;
  }

  .panel-body {
    max-height: 300px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
  }
}


/* IMAGES */

.card-img-top {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.nametext {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- NAVBAR -->
<div id="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

</div>


<!-- Cards -->
<div class="container">
  <!--  ROW 1   -->
  <!--         CARD 1 HECTOR -->
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">

      </div>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <a class="panel-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne"><span class="plus-minus"></span></a>
            <h3 class="nametext"> Hector Sr. </h3>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica. </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- card-body -->

      <img src="https://loe.org/content/2016-01-15/t-SOTU-President_Obama_Pete_Souza.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Responsive image">

    </div>
    <!-- card -->
  </div>

  <!--         CARD 2 ODALYS -->
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">

      </div>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <a class="panel-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo"><span class="plus-minus"></span></a>
            <h3 class="nametext"> Odalys Marrero </h3>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica. </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- card-body -->

      <img src="https://s1.r29static.com/bin/entry/576/720x864,85/2179893/image.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="Responsive image">

    </div>
    <!-- card -->
  </div>

  <!--         CARD 3 THE WORKERS -->
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
      </div>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion3" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
            <a class="panel-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree"><span class="plus-minus"></span></a>

            <h3 class="nametext"> The Workers </h3>

          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica. </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- card-body -->

      <img src="http://cdn.ipsnews.net/Library/2016/06/27232514444_bb9af40fcd_z.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Responsive image">

    </div>
    <!-- card -->
  </div>

  <!--    ROW 2 -->
  <!--         CARD 4 HECTOR LUIS -->
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">

      </div>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion4" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFour">

            <a class="panel-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion4" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour"><span class="plus-minus"></span></a>
            <h3 class="nametext"> Hector Luis </h3>
          </div>

          <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFour">

            <div class="panel-body">

              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- card-body -->

      <img src="https://c.stocksy.com/a/m8p500/z9/1388228.jpg?1571081157" class="card-img-top" alt="Responsive image">

    </div>
    <!-- card -->
  </div>

  <!--         CARD 5 PEDRO HECTOR -->
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">

      </div>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion4" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFive">
            <a class="panel-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion5" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive"><span class="plus-minus"></span></a>
            <h3 class="nametext"> Pedro Hector </h3>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFive">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica. </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- card-body -->

      <img src="https://marketplace.canva.com/MADFZPLwpN4/1/thumbnail_large/canva-young-mexican-man-MADFZPLwpN4.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Responsive image">

    </div>
    <!-- card -->
  </div>

  <!--         CARD 6 HECTOR MANUEL -->
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
      </div>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion6" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingSix">
            <a class="panel-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion6" href="#collapseSix" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSix"><span class="plus-minus"></span></a>

            <h3 class="nametext"> Hector Manuel </h3>

          </div>
          <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingSix">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica. </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- card-body -->

      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/85/c4/dd/85c4dd94e2bfda2f04e49bce1a729ed2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Responsive image">

    </div>
    <!-- card -->
  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```